# Framer Motion cannot animate rotateZ property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion, framerjs

I am using variants (Framer motion) to animate a component from `initial` to `animate` state in React, and one of the animated properties include `rotateZ` property, which **does not animate at all**. All others properties (`opacity` and `x`) animate. Can anyone tell me what's my mistake?

**Variant**

```js
const variants = {
    initial: {
        opacity: 0,
        x: -50,
        rotateZ: "-60deg",
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenPrimary
    },
    animate: {
        opacity: 1,
        x: 0,
        rotateZ: "0deg",
        transition: {
            ease: easeInOutCubicBezier,
            delay: 2.8,
            duration: 1
        }
    }
}
```

**Animation** *(I need this because I use `animation` for more animations later.)*

```js
useEffect(() => {
        animation.start("animate")
    }, [animation])
```

**Element**

```html
<motion.div variants={variants} animate={animation} whileTap="whileTap" initial="initial" onClick={toggleMenuHandler}>
...
</motion.div>
```

Comment: Can you show your `animate` variable? Also I think your `animate={animation}` should be `animate="animate"` if you're trying to achieve the variants.animate animations.

Comment: @crevulus My `animation` variable looks like: `const animation = useAnimation()`. Also, the reason I am using the `useAnimation` hook is because I am using it to coordinate animations with other components (those are working fine, as expected).

Comment: hmm... I'm quite new to Framer, so this may not fix it. But I do know that the string you pass to `animate` and `initial` should be the names of objects within your `variants` object. I don't think you can pass a var in there. Also try rotateZ(0) instead of using degree values.

Comment: @crevulus You can pass 'animation' variables to the animate prop. Google for the `useAnimation` hook. Super useful!

Comment: It works fine in a bare-bones sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sunset-q8gbd?file=/src/App.js. You must be doing something elsewhere to prevent or override the animation. When you say "it does not animate", is it stuck at the initial value or does it skip straight to 0deg?

Comment: @Cadin It stays at 0deg. All other values animate.

Comment: So the initial value isn't being set or is being overridden by something else in your code. You'll have to track that down. What you're showing here works fine, as you can see in the sandbox I posted.